SSIS/KingswaySoft - Conditional Field Mapping
We have built a CRM integration using SSIS/KingswaySoft that it is currently importing Contacts and handing the Insert/Update "Upsert" logic based on a field value we store in our source table.
It looks similar to the the following...

The business has now requested that the "address1_city" field is brought in for Inserts and is ignored for Updates since they want City values on existing records in CRM to remain the same.
Is there a way we can conditionally apply the "address1_city" field mapping so it only runs for Inserts and not for Updates?

This would be a limitation of SSIS where the metadata would need to remain static and cannot be changed dynamically. You may need to implement a design where the records are conditionally split so that the respective paths perform either an insert or update. The field ‘address1_city’ would be mapped in the CRM Destination with the action Insert and excluded in the Destination component that has the Update action.
If you have any other questions, please reach out to our Support Team at kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us and we will be happy to help or clarify.

Thank you.  I was hoping to avoid splitting out the logic, but you've confirmed this would  be the way to go.
